# Loss nan problem when using TFBertForSequenceClassification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I have a problem when training a model for multi-label text classification.
I'm working at Colab as follows:

```
def create_sentiment_bert():
  config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("monologg/kobert", num_labels=52)
  model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("monologg/kobert", config=config, from_pt=True)
  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=4.0e-6)
  loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
  metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy("accuracy")
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
  return model

sentiment_model = create_sentiment_bert()

sentiment_model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=2, shuffle=True, batch_size=250, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

The result is as follows:

Epoch 1/2
739/14065 [>.............................] - ETA: 35:31 - **loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00**

I have checked out my data: no nan or null or invalid values.

I tried different optimizers, # of epochs, learning rate, but had the same problem.

The number of labels is 52 and the distribution is as follows:

```
[Label] [Count]
501     694624
601     651306
401     257665
210     250352
307     170665
301     153318
306     147948
201     141382
302     113917
402     102040
606     101434
506     73492
305     69876
604     62056
403     57956
104     56800
107     55503
607     40293
503     36272
505     34757
303     26884
308     24539
304     22135
205     20744
509     19465
206     16665
508     15334
208     13335
603     13240
504     12299
602     10684
202     10366
209     8267
106     6564
502     5880
211     5804
207     2794
507     1967
108     1860
204     1633
105     1545
109     682
605     426
102     276
101     274
405     268
212     204
213     153
103     103
203     90
404     65
608     37
```

I'm a beginner in this area. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not about optimizer or anything like that. You'll have to check your input to the model again. What are you using as input? It is likely that there is something wrong there.

Comment: My data has three fields: (1) Text content (string, utf-8) (2) Label 1 of 5 diff
erent values (0~4) (3) Label 3 of 52 different values (100~608). It is ok in tra
ining models for classifying (2) with (1), but the problem occurs in training models for classifying (3) with (1).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have from_logits = False? The classifier head returns logits so unless you put a softmax activation within your model, you need to calculate the loss from logits.